# Retrofit: trying to get result from response

Tags: android, retrofit2

I just start to study Retrofit library, so really ask for a little help. I'm trying to get data from response, but I get only link to object.

```
interface IApi {
@GET("api")
Call<PostModel> getData();
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

public class App extends Application {

private static IApi siteApi;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://yesno.wtf/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
    siteApi = retrofit.create(IApi.class);
}

public static IApi getApi() {
    return siteApi;
}
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

class PostModel {

    @SerializedName("answer")
    @Expose
    private String answer;
    @SerializedName("forced")
    @Expose
    private Boolean forced;
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public Boolean getForced() {
        return forced;
    }

    public void setForced(Boolean forced) {
        this.forced = forced;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    }

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    App.getApi().getData().enqueue(new Callback<PostModel>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PostModel> call, Response<PostModel> response) {

            Log.e("Response", response.body().toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PostModel> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

I guess that there is some problems with variable types, but I'm not sure...I will appreciate any help.

**UPD:**
My logcat:

> ...
>
> D/OkHttp {"answer":"no","forced":false,"image":"https://yesno.wtf/assets/no/27-8befe9bcaeb66f865dd3ecdcf8821f51.gif"}
>
> D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (108-byte body)
>
> E/Response: com.testapp.retrofit.PostModel@9a74b2c

So the question is how I can get body of my responce? ("answer":"no","forced":false,"image":"https://yesno.wtf/assets/no/27-8befe9bcaeb66f865dd3ecdcf8821f51.gif")

Comment: what do you mean by 'link to object' ? There is no values in `response.body()`?

Comment: can you  please specify the problem along with logcat

Comment: what is your problem ? can you post the log cat

Comment: @RadekJ so the question is how to put values into responce.body()?

Comment: @Pratik Vyas, I have updated my question

Comment: @Khalid Taha, I have updated my question

Comment: Aren't they already there? What if you log `response.body().getAnswer()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your response

Your Model  PostModel looks Fine,
Try My working example in your manner

**The Interface**

```
  public interface ServiceInterface {

        @GET(HttpConstants.USERDATAJSON)
        Call<ListData>taskData(@Query("method")String method,@Query("stdID")int stdID);
    }
```

**The Service Class**

```
 public class ServiceClass {
        static ServiceInterface serviceInterface;
    //    public static final String baseUrl= HttpConstants.BASE_URL_GEONAME;
        public static final String baseUrl= HttpConstants.baseUrl;

        public static ServiceInterface connection(){
            if(serviceInterface==null){
                HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Response response=chain.proceed(chain.request());
                        return response;
                    }
                });
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .client(client)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                        .build();
                serviceInterface=retrofit.create(ServiceInterface.class);
            }
            return serviceInterface;
        }
    }
```

**The Call**

```
public void getTaskData(){
        ServiceInterface serviceInterface=ServiceClass.connection();
        Call<ListData> call=serviceInterface.taskData("getAllUsersSimple",0);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ListData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<ListData> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                Log.v("@@@Response",""+response.toString());
                if(response.isSuccess()){
                    listData=response.body();
                    dataList=listData.getData();
                    printStudentDetails(dataList);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.v("@@@Failure"," Message"+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

**The Model**

```
public class ListData {

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<DataPojo> data = null;
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private Integer code;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public List<DataPojo> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<DataPojo> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}

public class DataPojo {

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("user_name")
    @Expose
    private String userName;
    @SerializedName("user_age")
    @Expose
    private String userAge;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserAge() {
        return userAge;
    }

    public void setUserAge(String userAge) {
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }

}
```

for more referance please visit 
https://github.com/pratikvyas1991/NetworkingExample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/ims/tasol/networkingexample

Comment: @I.Ardel try to get reference from above ,It is working example